# Maven profile by user defined property

Tags: maven, properties, profile, defined

I have the following situation:

```
parent.pom
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>P1</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            whatever
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>P2</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>prop1</name>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <build>
            whatever
        </build>
    </profile>
```

Is there any way that only "mvn clean install" on child activates profile P2 without the need to specify profile like "mvn clean install -PP2" or "mvn clean install -Dprop1" or change settings.xml?

prop1 is not an  configuration or , it is just a config to activate profile P2.

I've tried:

```
child.pom
<properties>
    <prop1>exists</prop1>
</properties>
```

But it does not work as I expected due to http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html

So, has anyone ever did or needed something similar?

Comment: You are really describing an unconditional activation in which case you should set the `<activeByDefault>` to `true` for the profile `P2` (then both of the `profile`s `P1` and `P2` will be `active` by default).

Comment: Can i have this situation? 2 profiles active by default?

Comment: And `<exists>` and `<missing>` are meant to be used as conditions to drive the activation, typically for `<file>`s, although as of `Maven 2.0.9`, these could be interpolated. Supported variables are system properties like `${user.home}` and environment variables like `${env.HOME}`.

Comment: I must say I haven't tried activating 2 profiles using `<activeByDefault>`. I don't see a reason why it shouldn't be supported, though.

Comment: I did a quick test and confirmed it works - you can have as many profiles `<activeByDefault>` as you want. However, read up the warning from the doc on such a profile: "This profile will automatically be active for all builds unless another profile in the same POM is activated using one of the previously described methods. All profiles that are active by default are automatically deactivated when a profile in the POM is activated on the command line or through its activation config."

Comment: But how can i activate P2 without explicitly call "mvn clean install -PP2" or "mvn clean install -Dprop1"?

Comment: Thru `<activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>`? That's what the tag is for - activating profiles unconditionally.

Comment: Yes, but with 2 profiles active by default why P1 would not be activated when i call "mvn clean install"? The child pom properties tag cannot be used to do this activation.

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing here is really a case of wanting to activate a profile unconditionally. So you should be able to achieve that through `<activeByDefault>`.

In your case, if you set the `<activeByDefault>` of `P2` to `true`, you'll see that both the profiles `P1` and `P2` (and any such profiles) are activated by default (yes, you can activate as many `profile`s you want this way). You can verify this behavior this way:

`mvn help:active-profiles`

Careful with the warning on such profiles though:

> This profile will automatically be active for all builds unless
>   another profile in the same POM is activated using one of the
>   previously described methods. All profiles that are active by default
>   are automatically deactivated when a profile in the POM is activated
>   on the command line or through its activation config.

On `<exists>` and `<missing>`, they are really meant to be used for files, although as of `Maven 2.0.9`, these tags are allowed to be interpolated. Quoting the doc,

> This example will trigger the profile when the generated file
>   target/generated-sources/axistools/wsdl2java/org/apache/maven is
>   missing.

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <activation>
      <file>
        <missing>target/generated-sources/axistools/wsdl2java/org/apache/maven</missing>
      </file>
    </activation>
    ...
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

> As of Maven 2.0.9, the tags  and  could be
>   interpolated. Supported variables are system properties like
>   ${user.home} and environment variables like ${env.HOME}. Please note
>   that properties and values defined in the POM itself are not available
>   for interpolation here, e.g. the above example activator cannot use
>   ${project.build.directory} but needs to hard-code the path target.